# How to create a java.io.Writer from a file without clean the file in java?

Tags: java, ios, filewriter, writer

I have the code below.

```
Writer v_fw = new FileWriter(v_sheetWrapper.getFile());
```

Where `getFile()` is an XML file filled with my code. When I create the Writer through the code above, The XML file is cleaning. Can I write in the file without cleaning it?

Any additional information?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Do you mean you want to append to the file?

Comment: Note that appending to an *XML file* is basically a bad idea. You should almost certainly load the XML document, add more elements to it, then save the document again.

Comment: Thank you guys, there is a boolean argument that worked well to me. FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);